# How to give overlay permission by default?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Currently, I use the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
```

When this code is used, a setting screen which gives overlay permission is displayed.
But I want to give overlay permission by default when the application is installed.

The target android version is 6.0 or more.
How to give overlay permission by default?

Comment: what would be the point of requesting permissions if what you want were possible

Comment: Some application like facebook and uber, youtube have overlay permission by default.
I want to give overlay permission by default like this and display a button on other application when my application runs call.